# How to get correct ImageviewId after rotation of layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation, animator

I have a layout with 2*2/3*3/4*4... ImageView. and some of them randomly colored like this:

[image]

For ranodomly colored one of Imageview, I have Use this code:

```
Random random = new Random();

        id = array_image1.get(random.nextInt(array_image1.size()));


        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(findViewById(id), "backgroundResource", R.drawable.original_img, R.drawable.org_state).setDuration(1500);

        animator.setStartDelay(1500);
        animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
        animator.start();
```

And I'm handling some click event on colored ImageView like this:

```
     for (int i = 0; i < array_image11.size(); ++i) {
                final int btn = array_image11.get(i);

                findViewById(btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if ((findViewById(id)).equals(findViewById(btn)))
                        //Inform the user the button has been clicked
                        {

   //forward
   findViewById(id).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.original_img);

     }else {

                           //backward
                            Toast.makeText(StaticSpatial.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            }
```

There is no problem till above.

But When I'm adding a random rotate animation code like this:

```
            int n;
            int[] a=new int[]{1,2};
            final Random rnd = new Random();
            n=a[rnd.nextInt(a.length)];
            if(n==1)
            {
                 ObjectAnimator rotateAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(l4, View.ROTATION, 0, 90);
                rotateAnimator.setDuration(2000); // miliseconds
                rotateAnimator.start();n);


            }
            else
            {
              ObjectAnimator rotateAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(l4, View.ROTATION, 0, 90);
                rotateAnimator.setDuration(2000); // miliseconds
                rotateAnimator.start();
            }
```

After rotation image look like this(i.e. colored Imageview chage it's position):

[image]

After adding this rotate animation code my clickEvent not get correct ImageView id.
i.e. when imageview change it's position,their id should be go with that positon. but imageview id ramains at same postion.

So How to get required ImageviewId after rotation

**Update:**

After using azizbekian's answer(now using animator instead of animation) I found correct image-view id , but only first time.
i.e. first time when Activity starts  it works good but when I'm going to a new view(say 3*3) and return back again to this view(2*2),it returns wrong image-view id till Activity restarts again.see my updated code for ref.

**Explanation of working and issue:**

I have already said that there are many matix of Imageview such as 2*2/3*3/4*4..... So when we start Application first load 2*2 matrix of imageview and when we click the odd colored imageview it goes to 3*3 matrix but when we click other than odd colored imageviewthen it goes to next level say 3*3.So when app start  first time when I click on odd colored imageview it goes to 3*3 matrix but when return again on 2*2 after clicking other than odd colored imageview.and then again when we click on colored imageview it not get correct image id. and if any other query plz ask?

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: At least you guys give  reason for downvoting..

Comment: `but when I'm going to a new view, and return back again to this view` What does this mean? Maybe it is worth to share a code of that?  Tidy up your code, remove everything that is not related with the question (comments, whitespaces), give us (the readers of your question) a consice, reproducable, clean question.

Comment: it means as I have already said that there are many matix of Imageview such as 2*2/3*3/4*4..... So when we start Application first load 2*2 matrix of imageview and when we click the odd colored imageview it goes to 3*3 matrix but when we click other than odd colored imageviewthen it goes to next level say 3*3.So when app start  first time when I click on odd colored imageview it goes to 3*3 matrix but when return again on 2*2 after clicking other than odd colored imageview.and then again when we click on colored imageview it not get correct image id.

Comment: If u have any other query plz ask?

Comment: How do you go 3*3 and  again come to 2*2 please share that code.

Comment: See if else condition where click event handle @ReyanshMishra..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When *ImageView* changes it's position, their id should go with that position. But *ImageView* id remains at same position.

That's because you are using `Animation`, which in fact doesn't change your `View`'s position. What is does it makes an illusion of animation, so it only changes that view's matrix, but doesn't perform layout changes to the view.

Use [`Animator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html) API instead of [`Animation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html).

**Update**

Given this animation `xml`:

```
<set xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0" 
        android:toDegrees="90" 
        android:pivotX="50%" 
        android:pivotY="50%" 
        android:duration="2000" /> 
</set>
```

This can be substituted with following:

```
ObjectAnimator rotateAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourView, View.ROTATION, 0, 90);
rotateAnimator.setDuration(2000);
rotateAnimator.start();
```

**Update:**

Just set rotation zero at every load of view (or layout) like this:

```
mylayoutname.setRotation(0);
```

Because after rotation it doesn't go to zero degree automatically until activity stops.

Comment: Can u plz gave demo.

Comment: Post your `R.anim.clockwise`.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="90"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="2000" >
    </rotate>



</set>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of using rotation you can store the Ids of the ImageViews in a List or Array and the Id of the currently colored ImageView in a separated variable, and when you have to rotate instead you can simply select one random ImageView from the List/Array (excluding the currently colored one), remove the color from the previous one and color the new one.
By the way, when you have 3x3, 5x5, 7x7 etc. layouts is the middle ImageView never colored? 'Cause in those cases a rotation wouldn't change anything (visually, at least). I mean, a rotation works for choosing a random square in a layout of 2x2 squares, but not in any other case. Do you need to choose the squares randomly or do they need to always be chosen by a rotation? (I hope what I mean is clear...)